# How to remove the dynamic rows created in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am getting some records in php. At the bottom there is an 'Add More Rows', which clones the last row. There are some calculations also happening in this page. Now what i need is when i create add new rows, i need to show a 'x' mark at the end, and if i click that, it should delete the new created rows. How can i achieve that? My fiddle is below:

#### [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/euvof3xb/4/)

This is the jquery script which creates the clone element

```
$("#add_more").on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var clone = $("#table tbody tr:last").clone();
  $("#table tbody").append(clone);
});

$("#submit").on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert($("#cart1").serialize());
});
```

Comment: you can have a class and have something like this `$(document).on('click','.removerow',function(){
$(this).closest('tr').remove();
})`

Comment: here try this link https://jsfiddle.net/euvof3xb/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few edits to your code:

(1) In the `<thead>`, `<td>` should be `<th>`

(2) You only need to set the width on the `<th>` in the `<thead>`, and the `<td>` columns will keep the same width all the way down the table

(3) To aid styling, I added an appropriate class to each `<th>`

(4) I added a new `<td class="delTD">` at the end of each `<tr>`, and put a checkbox inside it. For original rows, the `<input type="checkbox">` control has the class `hidden`. Added rows have that class removed, making the `checkbox` visible only for added rows. When clicked, jQuery verifies that the row has a `newTR` class and, if present, deletes that row.

**Key changes to javascript:**

```
$(document).on('click', '.delINP', function(){
    var rr = $(this).closest('tr');
    rr.addClass('row-highlighted');
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this row?')){
        if (rr.hasClass('newTR')) rr.remove();
    }else{
        rr.removeClass('row-highlighted');
        rr.find('td.delTD input').prop('checked',false);
    }
});
```

and

```
$("#add_more").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var clone = $("#table tbody tr:last").clone();
    clone.addClass('newTR');
    clone.find('td.delTD input').removeClass('hidden');
    $("#table tbody").append(clone);
});
```

and **CSS:**

```
.hidden{display:none;}
.row-highlighted{background-color:red;}
```

<kbd>[**Updated jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/euvof3xb/14/)</kbd>

Comment: i should not be able to remove the existing records coming from the db. In the fiddle you can see 2 records, its coming from db. i should not be able to remove those rows. Only when i click Add New Rows, i should see the Remove checkbox or link.

Comment: @SanjuMenon Please try the jsFiddle at bottom of my answer and verify that it answers all your requirements *(DEL checkbox only visible on new rows, only new rows can be deleted, etc.)*

Comment: Its working absolutely fine. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Just one query. Is there a way if i check the checkbox, an confirm alert should come, Are you sure? you need to delete? If Yes delete it

Answer (score 1):

TRY This...

```
 $(".remove").on('click', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $("#table tbody tr:last").remove();
        });
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/78w7bgse/1/)

Comment: This answer always removes the last row. *What if the person has added four rows and wants to remove the 2nd-last row?*

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('click', "#add_more", function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var clone = $("#table tbody tr:last").clone();
if (!$(clone).find('td').hasClass('deleteRow')) {
    $(clone).append('<td class="deleteRow">X</td>');
}
$("#table tbody").append(clone);
```

});

```
$(document).on('click', '.deleteRow', function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', '.removerow', function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
})
```

Have a remove td in the rows and put a class on it and use the code above

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/euvof3xb/9/)

Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

> Description: Attach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements.

Comment: There is a small issue with this. I should be able to remove only newly created rows. As of now if you can see in the fiddle, there are 2 records showing which is coming from my db. If i click Add New Rows, its cloning a new row. i should be able to Remove that new newly created rows only. Not the other rows. I hope iam clear.

Comment: you can have a condition for that check if the index of the class is first then dont delete

Comment: But i cannot judge how many records will be coming from db. It depends. Just a small suggestion. Is it possible to add the Remove link in jquery, which i guess will solve the problem. As of now Remove link is added in the html part.

Comment: yes you can do that in jquery how do you need to add the remove on what instance?

Comment: When a new row is added i need an 'x' mark or delete link at the end. And when i click that that particular row should be deleted. Any instance is fine in this case

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
$("#add_more").on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var clone = $("#table tbody tr:last").clone();
   $(clone).append('<td class="deleteRow">X</td>');
  $("#table tbody").append(clone);
});


$('.deleteRow').unbind('click').bind('click',function(){
   $(this).closest('tr').remove();
}):
```

Comment: Note that `.bind` was deprecated in jQuery 1.7 and removed in ver 1.9. Since 1.7 we should use `.on()`